# How to install CodeRush Xpress on VS2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, coderush-xpress

I know that [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) is intended to be used on VS 2008 and not on VS 2005.
But since I can't migrate to VS2008 yet, I want to install it on VS2005 and don't care it's not supposed to work.

My base assumption is that it can be done, this is based on the fact that the rest of the free re factoring products from DevExpress do work on VS 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, and here what you need to do it.

Make sure VS is closed.
Install [RefactorCpp](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/).
Install [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/).
Apply this registry patch:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Developer Express]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Developer Express\CodeRush for VS\3.2]
    "HideMenu"=dword:00000000
    "LoadDXPlugInsOnly"=dword:00000000
    "StatusTextEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

Open VS.
Enable "DevExpress Tools" add-in in visual studio, Tools -> Add-in manager. Check the enable and startup checkboxes.

And now you are the proud user of CodeRush Xpress on VS 2005.

P.S. This works for me on:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
Version 8.0.50727.762  (SP.050727-7600)

Comment: Hi Alex!

Your answer used to work for me, but on a new install I do not manage to get CodeRush Xpress to work -- maybe because Refactor! for C++ has been updated in the meantime. I think the registry entries have changed (now a 9.1 key instead of a 3.2 key), and I applied your registry patch to that key, but still unsuccessful. Do you have an idea if the latest CodeRush Xpress can be installed with Visual Studio 2005?

Best regards
Christian

Comment: OK, found the solution for me. The CodeRush Xpress installer that can be downloaded from the DevExpress site is called CodeRushXpress-3.2.3.exe at the moment. I was not successful with this file. For me, installing with CodeRushXpress-9.1.3.exe that I downloaded maybe four weeks ago worked (also without applying the registry patch).

Answer (score 0):

Bad notice!

It's not possible because the plugin is for .NET Framework 3 and Visual Studio 2008 aka Orcas.

I try to install in Visual Studio 2005 but unsuccessfull.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I was able to install CodeRush Xpress on VS 2005 on top of Refactor! Pro without this registry hack. However, this was CodeRush Xpress 3.2.3 (plus Refactor! Pro 3.2.3) and I do know that the initial version of CodeRush Xpress could not be installed together with Refactor! This was fixed in 3.2.3.

Comment: The problem was not installing on top of Refactore Pro, but installing at all the free add on, as far as I know refactore pro is not free, but yes this will work as well and you won't need the registry patch, but you will need to pay for it (with real money) :)

Comment: Why would you event want to use CodeRush Xpress if you have Refactore Pro ?

Comment: You mentioned installing Refactor Cpp followed by CodeRush. I'm assuming there's no difference between that and having Refactor! Pro installed. It could just be that CodeRush Xpress 3.2.3 obviates the need for your solution? Also CodeRush Xpress adds additional features over Refactor! Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I think this hack won't work (no CodeRush in Add-in Manager) until you install Refactor!